# MetalKit view MTKView showing blurry stroke and extrapolating their designated path/size

Tags: ios, textures, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to plot squares using MetalKit. Each square has an origin and a size, like this:

```
Origin:

▿ (204.5746214852199, 62.83450704225352)
  - x : 204.5746214852199
  - y : 62.83450704225352

Size:

▿ (1.4612472963229992, 1.4612676056338028)
  - width : 1.4612472963229992
  - height : 1.4612676056338028
```

The problem is that when MetalKit draws those, each square is drawn a different weird way that exceeds the expected area and shape for what a square should look like (see image below) - yes, each red cluster should represent a single 1x1 square of the same size of those grey squares underneath. Furthermore, its borders are also blurry (this is a zoomed in image). I am using this sampler:

```c
constexpr sampler textureSampler(mag_filter::nearest,
                                 min_filter::nearest);
```

[image: greyscale pixel board with some red pixels]

In the image above, the greyscale squares is what each red square should be fitting to (their borders and exact position).

Any clue how to achieve this? Could MetalKit be losing decimal precision along the way? How can I make the squares edges sharp?

Here's my vertices function and position struct: https://github.com/s1ddok/MetalCoreGraphics/blob/d32c680a156548e20e9e9deb06e14cc260bcdea1/MetalCoreGraphics/Shaders.metal#L12-L30

Any leads would be super helpful here! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure things out in the end. It was a combination of several things.

1. The little squares (here named pixels) were exceeding their expected bounds because they were being antialiased. Since I'm using a `CGContext` to bridge between CPU and GPU memory ([strategy taken from here](https://medium.com/@s1ddok/combine-the-power-of-coregraphics-and-metal-by-sharing-resource-memory-eabb4c1be615)), I had to add the following code (both lines!):

```swift
context.setShouldAntialias(false)
context.setAllowsAntialiasing(false)
```

2. The pixels were blurred when zooming in because of the CALayer magnification filter, and not Metal's. The solution to that was quite simple:

```swift
layer.magnificationFilter = .nearest // Disables pixel interpolation when zooming in
```

3. Last but not least, the pixel coordinates (and size) weren't matching with the underlying pixel-perfect chess-looking board because the pixels I was drawing were actually `CGRects` (`context.addRects()`), and those CGRects had a too-precise width/height, often smaller than 1.00 (even though that wasn't the case in the original question, it had floating points which isn't really a thing when drawing individual pixels - there's no such thing as half of a pixel). So the solution to this was to use a canvas that has the exact number of pixels needed, and have all the CGRects I'm drawing to have a 1x1pt size. This way it's not only more performant (since there won't be floating point calculations all the time), but it will always be pixel perfect.

See the final result below (this view is zoomed in by 150 times using `UIScrollView`):

[image: final result]

Hope this helps somebody out there! Thanks everyone who contributed!

Comment: I have a different issue, but your third point gives me a hint to solve mine. Great explanation. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Metal Shader Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)
Metal stores the position values of Vertex in [single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

| Type | Description |
| --- | --- |
| float | A 32-bit floating-point. The float data type must conform to the IEEE 754 single precision storage format. |

This works well for small values, which it can represent precisely, but precision decreases as values increase because of floating-point rounding errors. As a result, Actor rendered far from the origin aren't positioned accurately (they're slightly misplaced).

Comment: I don't think that is it. In my experience, I can get pixels aligned with 32-bit floats.

Comment: Interesting! I was wondering why float data types weren't enough. As I learned from your references, it only has up to 23 bits (7 digits) of floating point precision and clearly my numbers are longer than that. Not sure how much of that precision drop would really affect my canvas visually, though? I mean, from the 8th FP number onwards, does it really make a visually distinct difference? The squares are very very different from what I'd expect, it's not just a couple subpixels away…

Comment: Metal coordinate space is -1 to 1, so they should be small numbers and are well representable by the 32-bit float and even 16-bit floats.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you debug the fragment that looks incorrect through https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/developing_and_debugging_metal_shaders
You'll be able to check what computation is being done for each output fragment and whether it is unexpected.